# Design for configurable JS component

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently working on a UI component that can be integrated using a script tag.

Clients create an account in the admin-dashboard, where they can find their personalised script tag, which they can then add to their website.

Right now they can modify the styling via a global config object or by overriding the styles in their css. But for the next release I would like to add a styling section to the admin-dashboard. So they should be able to login and change the color of the component.

So far so good, but I am really stuck on how to include the admin-dashboards config in the library. Of course the library should not make a network request to get the config, so it needs to be included in it.

Should I configure a build pipeline to rebuild the library and include the new config, whenever a user changes their settings in the dashboard?

I would love to learn common practices for this.

Thanks!

Comment: Your website could possibly expose a personalized style sheet users would include in their pages, together with your component. Any user webpage, hosted anywhere, would willingly accept your stylesheet exposed from your server. Another option would be to let users download the personalized style sheet so that they include it directly in their websites.

Comment: Hey @WiktorZychla, thanks for your answer. Yes that would certainly work, however it still remains the question how that Stylesheet would be created edited? Once the user changes the background color in the dashboard, how would that change propagate into the hosted filesheet?